# How to preview google-maps on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I'm really new in ReactJS. I want to visualize a map of Bulgaria and set markers in each city only when I receive rainfall data. For now I try with examples from this link: [React google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/)

But I get an error when placing the code in my file:

```
106:86-93 "export 'default' (imported as 'RainMap') was not found in './components/RainMap/RainMap'
```

Probably the error is very small but I do not know how to fix it.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';


const google = window.google;

const fetch = require("isomorphic-fetch");
const { compose, withProps, withHandlers } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} = require("react-google-maps");
const { MarkerClusterer } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer");

const MapWithAMarkerClusterer = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withHandlers({
    onMarkerClustererClick: () => (markerClusterer) => {
      const clickedMarkers = markerClusterer.getMarkers()
      console.log(`Current clicked markers length: ${clickedMarkers.length}`)
      console.log(clickedMarkers)
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 25.0391667, lng: 121.525 }}
  >
    <MarkerClusterer
      onClick={props.onMarkerClustererClick}
      averageCenter
      enableRetinaIcons
      gridSize={60}
    >
      {props.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.photo_id}
          position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }}
        />
      ))}
    </MarkerClusterer>
  </GoogleMap>
);

class DemoApp extends React.PureComponent {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ markers: [] })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = [
      // Length issue
      `https://gist.githubusercontent.com`,
      `/farrrr/dfda7dd7fccfec5474d3`,
      `/raw/758852bbc1979f6c4522ab4e92d1c92cba8fb0dc/data.json`
    ].join("")

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ markers: data.photos });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapWithAMarkerClusterer markers={this.state.markers} />
    )
  }
}

<DemoApp />
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import your RainMap component. Where in your directory is it stored? It seems to be trying to import from components folder -> RainMap folder -> RainMap.js